# Keeping HTML text from changing size upon changing browser width with ONLY HTML?

Tags: html, layout

Sorry for the oddly specific never-use-in-real-life question, but I'm stumped for a school assignment.

We were tasked with replicating a web page from scratch using HTML only (no CSS), and while the replicating part was easy, one of the optional components is making the web page static, so that it does not automatically resize upon changing the browser width.

I've ran across numerous solutions to this issue while searching the site but none of them have worked; either they used CSS or just didn't seem to catch (the  etc element).  If anyone has any insight into this, please let me know.  It's not essential to my grade, but its driving me insane.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: The question is not clear to me. I guess you need to set the width to the body, explicitly. It's not much what you can do in just HTML with something related to the browser width.

Comment: Font size does not change based on width without CSS or a viewport meta tag so your question does not make sense. There is no "etc element" either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a width attribute, in case you don't care about what version of html you need to use. For example, you can create a container from a table:

```
<table width="1000">
  <tr>
    <td>
       <!-- this will have a width of 1000 pixels -->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#adef-width-TABLE

In html5 the width attribute on the table element is obsolete

Comment: In what way does that prevent font size from changing which is what the question is asking?

Comment: This got it, thank you SO much.  Can't wait to just use CSS/HTML5 and be done with this stuff, lol